# Nifi : Why doesn't "Notify" reset counters and why does "Wait" count incorrectly?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to set up wait and notify processes to execute a final flow when several complex flows finish. However, I do not understand why the counters do not reset.

[image: Entire diagram of the flow]

On top of that, the wait process sends the flowfiles to the "success" path when the counter is greater than "Target Signal Count" attribute.

[image: Notify configuration]

Deleting and creating new cache clients and servers resets the counters and the problem does not reappear until I empty queues after the "Notify" process.[image: Wait configuration]

Answer (score 3):

With a hardcoded release signal identifier, the wait processor will pass the flowfiles to the success relationship only once. That is, when the signal counter reaches the target signal count of 2. When another flowfile is being generated, the same release signal identifier will be used. So the notify processor will increase the count beyond 2.

> On top of that, the wait process sends the flowfiles to the "success"
>   path when the counter is greater than "Target Signal Count" attribute.

No. Flowfiles are send to the success relationship when signal count exactly matches your target signal count.

You can solve this problem in two ways.

First you can to use a dynamic release signal identifier, that changes every time a new flowfile is generated. `GenerateFlowFile` creates a filename attribute, which you can use. This way you are using a new cache key for every new flowfile, so you have a new counter for every new root flowfile.

Second you can use [**PutDistributedMapCache**](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDistributedMapCache/) to manually update the counter.

I create a flow to test the first solution:

[image]

GenerateFlowFile contains some simple text:

[image]

SplitText simply splits the text, resulting in one flowfile per line. Then you route the original flowfile to the Wait processor:

[image]

Notice that I use `${filename}` to set a dynamic release signal identifier. `${fragment.count}` is provided by the `SplitText` processor and holds the total number of splits or lines in that specific use case. Now you have to increase the counter with `Notify` processor:

[image]

Once all lines where routed to `Notify` a signal for the counter name `chunks` will be released and the `Wait` processor will route the original flowfile to the success relationship.

PS: to dive deeper into Wait/Notify you might check out this blog post: [How to wait for all fragments to be processed, then do something?](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/).